# IBM App Connect Enterprise - Service Orchestration without an IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

According to the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac04740_.htm) it seems to use the     Aggregate Control Node an IBM MQ is required.

I need to make a service call, get an array of values, and pass those values one by one to a different service in an iterative manner.

I was trying a sample, then when deploying the PI only this error message popped up.

`The node of type 'AggregateReply' named 'getGetLoanInfoOrch (Implementation).Aggregate Reply' requires a queue manager to be specified on the integration node.`

Can't this be done without using an IBM MQ?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked to the IIB 9 documentation. If you can switch to IIB 10 or ACE 11, you have the possibility to use the [Group nodes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc34061_.html), which are a [stateless alternative](https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2018/10/02/ibm-integration-bus-10-0-0-14-is-now-available/) to the Aggregate nodes.

Comment: Apologies, I have tagged the wrong documentation, Yes I'm using ACE 11, your answer will be helpful to explore the nodes. Thanks a lot.